# Using python if there is a diamond structure the super() at the left corner refers to the class on the right corner, not that of the top one. Why?

Tags: python, inheritance, diamond-problem

I am using (and learning) Python3
I have a top class (geometry_0) , defining the structure of a geometry description, and a children of it (geometry(geometry_0)) that gives the structure of a modified geometry. The derived classes, eg. simple geometry: parabola(geometry_0), and a modified one parabola_shifted(geometry,parabola). Geometry contains a super() function, but it refers to parabola instead of geometry_0. I am happy with that, but I do not understand why.
It is a kind of diamond structure, maybe that can be behind?  But what happens during compilation?

The simplified dummy code is:

```
class Geometry_0():

    @classmethod
    def x2y(cls,geom_pars: dict, x: float) -> float:
        print('in Geometry_0')
        return NotImplemented

class Geometry(Geometry_0):

    @classmethod
    def transform(cls,geom_pars: dict, x_child: float) ->float:

        return NotImplemented

    @classmethod
    def x2y(cls,geom_pars: dict, x_child: float):
        print('in Geometry')
        x_parent = cls.transform(geom_pars,x_child)

        return super().x2y(geom_pars,x_parent) # that should refer to geometry_0 ??

class Parabola(Geometry_0): # y = a * x**2

    @classmethod
    def x2y(cls, geom_pars, x):
        print('in Parabola')
        a = geom_pars['a']
        return a * x**2

class Parabola_shifted(Geometry,Parabola): # y = a * (x-x0)**2

    @ classmethod
    def transform(cls,geom_pars: dict, x_child: float) ->float:
        x0 = geom_pars['x0']
        x_parent = x_child - x0

        return x_parent
    # x2y is inherited from geometry, that calls the super().x2y

print('parabola')
print(Parabola.x2y({'a': 1},2))
print('shifted parabola')
print(Parabola_shifted.x2y({'a':1, 'x0': 2}, 2))
```

The output is:

```
parabola at 2: y= 1* 2**2 = 4
in Parabola
4
shifted parabola at 2: y= 1* (2-2)**2 = 0
in Geometry
in Parabola
0
```

'

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the Python MRO (Method Resolution Order).

Here a good tutorial: https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/python-tutorial-understanding-python-mro-class-search-path

For more details you can have a look a this: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/

Example: D extends B and C, themselves extending A.

```
class A:
    def display(self):
        print('A')

class B(A):
    def display(self):
        print('B')
        super().display()

class C(A):
    def display(self):
        print('C')
        super().display()

class D(B, C):
    def display(self):
        print('D')
        super().display()

d = D()
d.display()
```

`super` will follow the MRO and, depending on both the class context in which it’s called and the instance’s type, it will find the next object in the precedence list

output:

```
D
B
C
A
```

The algorithm begins with the inheritance graph as declared and removes duplicated entries by keeping only their last occurrence

With the previous example:

```
D, B, object , C, object ⇒ D, B, C, object
```

Comment: Then am I right, in the following?:  the search path in your code is DBACA. The old MRO removes the same classes behind, while the new one removes the same classes before, so in python <2.3 the MRO is BDAC, but for higher versions it is DBCA

Comment: I think that it is DBAC for python <2.3.

Comment: Sorry, yes, DBAC, I just cannot correct it